# Extract particular value from .txt file and place in excel

Tags: excel, vba, text

I need to extract particular data from a text file and place it in Microsoft excel, where a template is already ready.

Example of my text file content:

```
     (3space)    (2s)   (2s)         (3s)                 (18s)
[key]   0.00-34.00  sec  2.08 minute   526 km/sec                  auto   
[key]   0.00-34.00  sec  1.88 minute   474 Km/sec                  auto    
[key]   0.00-34.00  sec  1.49 minute   376 km/sec                  auto    
[key]   0.00-34.00  sec  1.25 minute   316 km/sec                  auto    
[key]   0.00-34.00  sec  3.05 minute   771 km/sec                  van  
[key]   0.00-34.00  sec  2.79 minute   705 km/sec                  van  
[key]   0.00-34.00  sec  2.83 minute   715 km/sec                  van  
[key]   0.00-34.00  sec  2.83 minute   716 km/sec                  van
```

and excel sheet template looks like: [excel sheet is ready with headings,rows and columns](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hZZyc.png)
and this template will be created manually.

Expected:
1.The value in .txt file with **km/sec and auto** should be listed in second column

2.The value in .txt file with **km/sec and van** should be listed in third column

ex:this is how the expected template should look like :[template after the values entered](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rwZR0.png)

**added:**

When i want to read from 3 files and place the value in single template :[image: values from 3 files into single template]
instance-1 from file1

instance-2 from file2

instance-3 from file3

for instance 1 i made the following changes:

```
 Const strFile = "C:\file1.txt"

        ' Row Array
    Dim vntFR As Variant: vntFR = Array(89, 89)
    ' Column Array
    Dim vntCC As Variant: vntCC = Array(2, 8)
```

want to know How to proceed with file2 and file3

Comment: I'd suggest you to use `Split()` function

Answer (score 1):

One possible way would be to use File I/O, together with Mid. Something like this seems to work on your sample data:

```
Sub sGetDistanceData(strFile As String)
    On Error GoTo E_Handle
    Dim intFile As Integer
    Dim strInput As String
    Dim lngVan As Long
    Dim lngAuto As Long
    intFile = FreeFile
    Open strFile For Input As intFile
    lngVan = 6    ' the first row of van data
    lngAuto = 6    ' the first row of auto data
    Do
        Line Input #intFile, strInput
        If Mid(strInput, 68, 4) = "auto" Then
            ActiveSheet.Cells(lngAuto, 2) = Mid(strInput, 38, 5)
            lngAuto = lngAuto + 1
        ElseIf Mid(strInput, 68, 3) = "van" Then
            ActiveSheet.Cells(lngVan, 3) = Mid(strInput, 38, 5)
            lngVan = lngVan + 1
        End If
    Loop Until EOF(intFile)
sExit:
    On Error Resume Next
    Reset
    Exit Sub
E_Handle:
    MsgBox Err.Description & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "sGetDistanceData", vbOKOnly + vbCritical, "Error: " & Err.Number
    Resume sExit
End Sub
```

I've kept separate counts of the number of Van/Auto data imported, just in case there are an unequal number.

Regards,

Answer (score 0):

### Data From Text File

```vb
Sub DataFromTextFile()

    ' Text File Address
    Const strFile = "C:\Test1.txt"
    Const cCriteria As Long = 67  ' Criteria Position
    Const cPosition As Long = 38  ' Target Position
    Const cChars As Long = 5      ' Target Chars

    ' Criteria Array
    Dim vntC As Variant: vntC = Array("auto", "van")
    ' Row Array
    Dim vntFR As Variant: vntFR = Array(6, 6)
    ' Column Array
    Dim vntCC As Variant: vntCC = Array(2, 3)

    Dim vntL As Variant           ' Criteria Length Array
    Dim vntR As Variant           ' Target Row Counter Array
    Dim LB As Long                ' Array Lower Bound
    Dim UB As Long                ' Array Upper Bound
    Dim i As Long                 ' Array Element Counter
    Dim t As Long                 ' Total Records Counter
    Dim lngFile As Long           ' Text File Number
    Dim strLine As String         ' Current Line (in Text File)

    ' Calculate Lower and Upper Bounds.
    LB = LBound(vntC): UB = UBound(vntC)

    ' Resize Criteria Length Array to the size of Criteria Array.
    ReDim vntL(UB) As Long
    ' Calulate the length of each element in Criteria Array and write
    ' the calculated values to Criteria Length Array.
    For i = LB To UB: vntL(i) = Len(vntC(i)): Next i
    ' Resize Target Row Counter Array to the size of Criteria Array.
    ReDim vntR(UB) As Long

    ' Aquire Text File Number.
    lngFile = FreeFile()          '

    ' Write Text File to memory.
    Open strFile For Input As #lngFile
        ' Loop through lines of Text File.
        Do While Not EOF(lngFile)
            ' Write current line of Text File (from memory) to Current Line.
            Line Input #lngFile, strLine
            ' Loop through elements of Arrays.
            For i = LB To UB
                ' Check if Current Criteria is found at current Target Position.
                If Mid(strLine, cCriteria, vntL(i)) = vntC(i) Then
                    ' Count Target Row by increasing the current value
                    ' of the current element in Target Row Counter Array.
                    vntR(i) = vntR(i) + 1
                    ' Write Current Target Value to ActiveSheet.
                    Cells(vntFR(i) + vntR(i) - 1, vntCC(i)) _
                      = Trim(Mid(strLine, cPosition, cChars))
                    ' Count Total (All) Records so far.
                    t = t + 1
                    Exit For
                End If
            Next i
        Loop
    Close #1

    MsgBox "Total Records Found: " & t, vbInformation

End Sub
```

All those arrays are not for speed, but to be able to easily change the values of the variables or more importantly to add more criteria values e.g.:

```
' Criteria Array
Dim vntC As Variant: vntC = Array("auto", "van", "bike", "plane")
' Row Array
Dim vntFR As Variant: vntFR = Array(6, 6, 6, 6)
' Column Array
Dim vntCC As Variant: vntCC = Array(2, 3, 4, 5)
```

## EDIT

This version consists of DataFromText where you change the names of the text files and the column pairs respectively, and of a NEW version of DataFromTextFile
where I have already changed the row numbers to 89 as requested. Best rename or delete the old version of DataFromTextFile.

```
Option Explicit

Sub DataFromText()

    Dim vntFiles As Variant   ' Files Array
    Dim i As Long             ' Arrays Elements Counter

    ' Files
    vntFiles = Array("C:\Test1.txt", "C:\Test2.txt", "C:\Test3.txt")
    ' If you add more files, you have to add more column pairs and increase
    ' the ubound of vntColumns i.e. the number in braces.
    Dim vntColumns(2) As Variant

    ' Column Pairs
    vntColumns(0) = Array(2, 8)
    vntColumns(1) = Array(3, 9)
    vntColumns(2) = Array(4, 10)

    For i = 0 To UBound(vntFiles)
        DataFromTextFile CStr(vntFiles(i)), vntColumns(i)
    Next i

End Sub

Sub DataFromTextFile(FilePath As String, TargetColumns As Variant)

    ' Text File Address
    Dim strFile As String
    strFile = FilePath
    Const cCriteria As Long = 67  ' Criteria Position
    Const cPosition As Long = 38  ' Target Position
    Const cChars As Long = 5      ' Target Chars

    ' Criteria Array
    Dim vntC As Variant: vntC = Array("auto", "van")
    ' Row Array
    Dim vntFR As Variant: vntFR = Array(89, 89)
    ' Column Array
    Dim vntCC As Variant: vntCC = TargetColumns

    Dim vntL As Variant           ' Criteria Length Array
    Dim vntR As Variant           ' Target Row Counter Array
    Dim LB As Long                ' Array Lower Bound
    Dim UB As Long                ' Array Upper Bound
    Dim i As Long                 ' Array Element Counter
    Dim t As Long                 ' Total Records Counter
    Dim lngFile As Long           ' Text File Number
    Dim strLine As String         ' Current Line (in Text File)

    ' Calculate Lower and Upper Bounds.
    LB = LBound(vntC): UB = UBound(vntC)

    ' Resize Criteria Length Array to the size of Criteria Array.
    ReDim vntL(UB) As Long
    ' Calulate the length of each element in Criteria Array and write
    ' the calculated values to Criteria Length Array.
    For i = LB To UB: vntL(i) = Len(vntC(i)): Next i
    ' Resize Target Row Counter Array to the size of Criteria Array.
    ReDim vntR(UB) As Long

    ' Aquire Text File Number.
    lngFile = FreeFile()          '

    ' Write Text File to memory.
    Open strFile For Input As #lngFile
        ' Loop through lines of Text File.
        Do While Not EOF(lngFile)
            ' Write current line of Text File (from memory) to Current Line.
            Line Input #lngFile, strLine
            ' Loop through elements of Arrays.
            For i = LB To UB
                ' Check if Current Criteria is found at current Target Position.
                If Mid(strLine, cCriteria, vntL(i)) = vntC(i) Then
                    ' Count Target Row by increasing the current value
                    ' of the current element in Target Row Counter Array.
                    vntR(i) = vntR(i) + 1
                    ' Write Current Target Value to ActiveSheet.
                    Cells(vntFR(i) + vntR(i) - 1, vntCC(i)) _
                      = Trim(Mid(strLine, cPosition, cChars))
                    ' Count Total (All) Records so far.
                    t = t + 1
                    Exit For
                End If
            Next i
        Loop
    Close #1

    MsgBox "Total Records Found: " & t, vbInformation

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi, This worked for a single file, to read data from text file and place it in a template prepared. Can i know how to modify the above code to read data from multiple files(test1,test2,test3) from the same path and i have multiple templates ready in the same excel one below the other.

Comment: Look at the constants and see what has to be changed. Obviously the filename and probably the first column. If that's all, then the sub can be written to have those arguments similar to the other solution. Please come back to me if you think some other constants will change.